# SignalR Unexpected character encountered while parsing value

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr

I am trying to create a signalR hub in asp.net but i have problems with it on server. It works ok on my local machine. The error i get it:

> Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0.

The code is:

```
 var hubConnection = new HubConnection("http://server_name/appName/");
 hubConnection.Start().Wait();
```

I can see that the hubConnection url is correct because it's the same as the one provided in the constructor, which means: `http://server_name/appName/signalr/`

The full stacktrace is:

> at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseValue()    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ReadInternal()    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.Read()    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.ReadForType(JsonReader
>   reader, JsonContract contract, Boolean hasConverter)    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader
>   reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader,
>   Type objectType)    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type
>   objectType)    at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String
>   value, Type type, JsonSerializerSettings settings)    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T](String value,
>   JsonSerializerSettings settings)    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T](String value)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.Transports.TransportHelper.b__1(String
>   raw)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.TaskAsyncHelper.<>c__DisplayClass19`2.<Then>b__17(Task`1
>   t)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.TaskAsyncHelper.TaskRunners`2.<>c__DisplayClass42.<RunTask>b__41(Task`1
>   t)

Also, on IIS i don't have forms authentication, only the Anonymous Authentication is enabled.

PS: i have read the other questions related to this but none of them applies here. (the questions i've read are: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20725273/signalr-net-client-unexpected-character-encountered-while-parsing-value), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22808057/signalr-hub-connection-error) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12730096/signalr-unexpected-character-encountered-while-parsing-value))

Answer (score 0):

This is basically Json.NET trying to parse a string and seeing the '<' character at the beginning which means it's not proper json.

There's usually two general possibilities:

1. Your url returns HTML and that first character is the start of the document
2. Your url return XML

Try catching the string and see what it is.

Comment: How could i catch the string? Because fiddler doesn't show the signalr request...

Comment: I'm guessing you're hooking up a website to the endpoint? You could use the browser debugging tools to look at the network activity.